Can not connect to h2-database in spring boot
I am writing a REST API in spring boot and I can not connect to h2 in spring boot. This error is showing when I test the connection. Please help. Thank you in advance.
Here is my application.properties file.
spring.application.name=demo
server.port=8081

# H2 Database Configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.platform=h2

# Hibernate Configuration
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

# H2 Console Configuration
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

I tried creating a directory called test in C:\Users\zoho but it did not work. what should I do?

The url put on the website is different

@SquidXTV what do you mean url is different? can you please clarify? what should I do?

The JDBC URL mentioned in the application.properties file and that mentioned on the login console is different.
In the login console update the url to the value mentioned in application.properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
Refer the image to update the property accordingly.

